# Creating ASP.NET Identity user using SQL

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

In our ASP.NET MVC Core app we are using [ASP.NET Idenity](https://www.asp.net/identity) to implement user management.

**Question**: Instead of using ASP.NET user interface, how can we directly create a user into the SQL Database (using a SQL statement etc.)? Will creating a user directly in ASPNETUsers table cause any issue? **Note**: We need to populate built-in identity table `ASPNETUsers` from a list of users. Password can be anything and no specific role is required.

Comment: Have you tried? What happened when you tested this?

Answer (score 8):

Here is the insert script for AspNetUsers

```
INSERT [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id], [AccessFailedCount], [ConcurrencyStamp], 
[Email], [EmailConfirmed], [LockoutEnabled], [LockoutEnd], [NormalizedEmail], 
[NormalizedUserName], [PasswordHash], [PhoneNumber], [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
[SecurityStamp], [TwoFactorEnabled], [UserName]) VALUES 
(N'0633e088-30a6-444f-9603-70d7c26748ef', 0, 
N'd2feada1-c7db-4f5a-801c-4ae5c990a49d', N'user@domain.com', 1, 1, NULL, 
N'USER@DOMAIN.COM', N'USER@DOMAIN.COM', 
N'AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEBqhdvkH3O3glua9IFU+LDamc3mj03dPQ/8brAW34GTN6kxMOqs5je90FNn7fuNleQ==', 
N'+10001234567', 1, N'6123adf0-fc53-4abb-b6a4-52d164da4e4f', 0, N'user@domain.com')
GO
```

Of course you will need to generate your own Guids and hash your own password.

Comment: How can I create password hash? Can I copy from my local to the server?